# how to round numbers after decimal point in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I am using numpy round function its working well all aspects but when there is 15.65 it should give 15.7 but its giving 15.6. is there any other method to do this ? because i read many threads numpy have this issue.

```
df1['result']=df1['a'].apply(lambda x: np.round(x, decimals=1))
```

Comment: From the numpy docs: For values exactly halfway between rounded decimal values, NumPy rounds to the nearest even value. Thus 1.5 and 2.5 round to 2.0, -0.5 and 0.5 round to 0.0, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a trick that adds a very small amount to the data and round. But you need to assure that the delta is smaller than your resolution.

```
df = pd.Series(np.arange(0,100,0.05))

df.round(1).head()    
# 0    0.0
# 1    0.0
# 2    0.1
# 3    0.2
# 4    0.2
# dtype: float64

(df+1e-10).round(1).head()    
# 0    0.0
# 1    0.1
# 2    0.1
# 3    0.2
# 4    0.2
# dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

Python inbuilt round() function rounds off to the given number of digits and returns the floating point number, if no number of digits is provided for round off , it rounds off the number to the nearest integer.

```
array = [15.65, 15.64, 15.61, 15, 15.94, 15.96]
print([round(i,1) for i in array])
```

It gives output [15.7, 15.6, 15.6, 15, 15.9, 16.0]

Answer (score 0):

Use `round()` python builtin function

```
In [1]: round(15.65, 1)
Out[1]: 15.7
```

In your case:

```
df1['result']=df1['a'].apply(lambda x: round(x, 1))
```